# Frequency: Every three weeks or more / At least every three weeks / etc

Tags: expressions, time, recurring-events

I would like to express that an action should be done every three weeks, but that longer periods are also acceptable.

Which of the following is the simplest, clearest, and most natural way to express that? And if any of the expressions below are problematic, in what way are they?

Take the pill:

> 1. Every three weeks or more
> 2. At least every three weeks
> 3. Every three or more weeks
> 4. Every three weeks or longer
> 5. Every three weeks or less frequently

Comment: At first reading, all alternatives are confusing. Why start with 'Every three weeks' which is not quite what you mean? Perhaps, "Once in three or more weeks" would be more like what actually mean to say.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would say "*No more than* once every three weeks" or perhaps "*At most* (once) every three weeks".

> 1.) Every three weeks or more

Unclear: You're trying to say "Can I wait *longer* than every three weeks?" but it can easily be interpreted as "Can I take this more *often* than every three weeks?"

> 2.) At least every three weeks.

Incorrect: Suggests that the *longest* I am allowed to wait between doses is three weeks.

> 3.) Every three or more weeks
>
> 4.) Every three weeks or longer
>
> 5.) Every three weeks or less frequently

All somewhat awkward to say, but clear in that you won't be misunderstood.